# Enable Button if One of Three Textboxes across 3 tabs has content

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I have a Button that lives outside a tab control element. Each Tab on the TabControl has either a text box for manual text entry or a search tool to look up something from a database (the value of which will also be written to the label in tab 2 & 3).

I want to enable the Print button if the textbox has content ***or*** a variable that is populated from a database query on the selected tab has content.

What would be the best way to do this, given a button can only be bound to one source? I pondered having a staging variable, but then that would also be only bound to one element.

Any ideas? I'm really new to data-binding and I'm struggling to get my head around some of the concepts.

It doesn't help that the back-end is in VB because i'm porting a number of WinForms apps to WPF and I want to do them properly.

Quick XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Name="Main1" x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" SizeToContent="Height">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel >
            <Grid x:Name="Activity" Margin="5,5,5,0" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <TabControl x:Name="Main_Tabs" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Gainsboro">
                        <TabItem x:Name="T1" Header="H1" >
                            <Grid Margin="5">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Address:</Label>
                                <TextBox x:Name="Single_Address" 
                                                 Margin="5,3" 
                                                 SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" 
                                                 IsManipulationEnabled="True" 
                                                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                                                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                                 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                                                 Language="en-GB" Height="80">
                                </TextBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="T2" Header="H2" >
                            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Grid_Elucid_Label2">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>

                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Address:</Label>
                                <Label x:Name="Elucid_Address" 
                                                 Margin="5,3" 
                                                 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="80">
                                </Label>
                            </Grid>

                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="T3" Header="H3">
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid_Sage_Label" Margin="5">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Address:</Label>
                                <Label x:Name="Sage_Address" Margin="5,3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="80">
                                </Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <Button x:Name="Print_Button" Content="Print" Padding="10" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Bind the Labels and the TextBox to properties of a view model, and bind the Button to another property of the same view model that is being set based on the values of the other three properties.

Answer (score 1):

**#1 VM with few textproperties to evaluate**

if you have just a few text properties and use a VM, you can go with some triggers.
I wrote this by hand so I'm sorry if the syntax isn't a 100% match.

```
<button content="print">
  <button.style>
    <style targettype={x:type button}>
      <style.triggers>
        <multidatatrigger>
          <multidatatrigger.conditions>
            <condition Binding="{Binding VMprop1}" Value="">
            <condition Binding="{Binding VMprop2}" Value="">
            <condition Binding="{Binding VMprop3}" Value="">
          </multidatatrigger.conditions>
          <multidatatrigger.setters>
            <setter property="IsEnabled" value="false"/>
          </multidatatrigger.setters>
        </multidatatrigger>
      </style.triggers>
    </style>
  </button.style>
<button>
```

## 2 no VM or a lot of properties to evaluate

bind to the TextChanged of all TextBoxes and evaluate their state, and set the IsEnabled from your button (if you want use a Dependency Property)

```
<button x:Name="btn1" content="print" IsEnabled="{Binding CanPrint}"/>
<textbox x:Name="tb1" TextChanged="EvaluateCanPrint"/>
<textbox x:Name="tb2" TextChanged="EvaluateCanPrint"/>
<textbox x:Name="tb3" TextChanged="EvaluateCanPrint"/>
<textbox x:Name="tb4" TextChanged="EvaluateCanPrint"/>
...

private void EvaluateCanPrint() {
  // ViewModel.EvaluateCanPrint();
  ViewModel.CanPrint = 
    !string.isNullOrEmpty(tb1.Text) &&
    !string.isNullOrEmpty(tb2.Text) &&
      ...;
}

// Original answer
//private void EvaluateTextChanged() {
//  if (string.isNullOrEmpty(tb1.Text) &&
//      string.isNullOrEmpty(tb2.Text) &&
//      ...)
//  {
//    btn1.IsEnabled = false;
//  }
//}
```

Comment: I'm not sure #1 will work because it needs to evaluate 3-4 properties/variables on different tabs. The latter as a sub with OR comparisons might well work.